# Capturing functional requirements on a non-interaction based system

Tags: uml, actor, use-case

I'm trying to find the functional requirements for a system under development. The problem is that the system shall act on itself on scheduled intervals. For instance, the system shall run an optimization algorithm every 20 minutes. It shall request data from other services on another time interval etc.

I'm having trouble modeling this behavior using use cases. I have considered using time as an actor but that would yield a very complex diagram. Is there any other method for finding the functional requirements for a system that acts without external interaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the problem having a complex use case diagram if your system is complex?  Your solution is ok: each operation that should be invoked on a timely basis should be connected to the time actor.

Answer (score 0):

UML Actors can be summarised as "roles with goals".  therefore instead of using one actor for time linked to several usecases.  Use several Actors linked to one usecase for each seperate timer event/ interval.